# Replacing an octagonal ceiling fan power outlet

Tags: electrical

How do I remove and replace the octagonal power box in the ceiling as one tip (for screwing the fan motor body into) is broken?  I assume I have to remove from within the attic as there are two screws coming from the attic into the power box that will not back out.

Comment: If you can get into the attic, it will definitely give you a better idea of what you're dealing with.

Comment: Are you talking about the screw tab (ear) on a plastic box is broken off? Or a metal box has a broken screw left in the ear?

Comment: Since @ArchonOSX mentions the ears on a box, others should note that the bent over ears on a metal box aren't suitable for hanging a fan. Fan support should pass through the box to structure, or use a fan rated box that has stronger structure built in. (The original question refers to a "tip", which could be the support post in a fan rated box.)

Comment: @TimB Good point. I like to buy the ceiling hugger style fans and mount them right to the ceiling in an old-work situation like this. Then the OP wouldn't have to worry about replacing the box.

Answer (score 1):

Ceiling fans need to have listed Boxes NEC 314.27.C. If they are large ones there may be more hardware in the attic that you cannot access from below.
Lighter ones many times are screwed to a 2”x4” or 2”x6” that is screwed or nailed to the ceiling trusses. You may have to remove this brace to pull the box.